# How to code ARM interrupt functions in C

Tags: embedded, interrupt, bare-metal, cortex-m

I am using [arm-none-eabi-gcc](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) toolchain, v 4.8.2, on LinuxMint 17.2 64b.

I am, at hobbyist level, trying to play with a TM4C123G board and its usual features (coding various blinkies, uart things...) but always trying to remain as close to the metal as possible without using other libraries (eg CMSIS...) whenever possible. Also no IDE (CCS, Keil...), just Linux terminal windows, the board and I... All that mostly for education purpose.

The issue : I am stuck trying to implement the usual interrupt functions like :

EnableInt (clearing bit 0, bit I, of special registry PRIMASK) :

```
CPSIE  I
```

WaitForInt :

```
WFI
```

DisableInt :

```
CPSID  I
```

Eg, I added this function to my .c file for EnableInt :

```
void EnableInt(void)
{    __asm("    cpsie   i\n");
}
```

... this compiles but the execution does not seem to work properly (in the simplest blinky.c version, I cannot get any LED action once I have called EnableInt() in the C code). The blinky.c code can be found [here](http://codepad.org/ud39KwZG).

What would be the proper way to write these interrupt routines in a .c file (ideally without using other libraries, but just setting/clearing bits of the appropriate registers...)?

EDIT : removed the bx lr instructions - but EnableInt() does not seem to work any better - still looking for a solution.

EDIT2 : Actually the function EnableInt(), defined as above, is now working. My SysTick_Handler was mapped incorrectly to the Interrupt Vector table in the startup file (while my original problem was the bx lr instructions which I removed in Edit1).

Comment: Think about what happens when the compiler's default function prologue sets up a stack frame on entry to `EnableInt`, pushes the return address, then your asm forces a return without tearing down that stack frame? Or worse, you have optimisation turned on and the asm gets inlined at the call site, so you "return" to nonsense. You absolutely _do not_ want `bx lr` in an inline asm.

Comment: For Cortex-M CPUs usning AAPCS you do not need assembler. Also, do not lock the global interrupt unless **absolutely** necessary. And read about CMSIS, use the standard way, not some homebrew stuff. Why do you branch somewhere after manipulating PRIMASK anyway??

Answer (score 2):

The ARM Cortex-M4 CPU which your Tivia MCU incorporates does basically not require the software environment to take special action for entry/exit the  interrupt handler. The only requirement is to use the AAPCS calling standard, which should be the default with gcc if compiling for this CPU.

The CPU is supported by some tightly coupled "core" peripherals provided by ARM. These are standard for most (if not all) Cortex-M3/4 MCUs. MCU vendors can configure some features, but the basic operation is always the same.

To simplify software development, ARM has introduced the CMSIS software standard. This at least consists of some header-files which unify access to the core-peripherals and use of special CPU instructions. Among those are intrinsics to manipulate the special CPU registers like PRIMASK, BASEMASK, OPTION, etc. Another header provides definitions of the core peripherals and functions to manipulate some of them where a simple access is not sufficient.

So, one of these peripherals supports the CPU for interrupt handling: The `NVIC` (nested vector-interrupt controller). This prioritises interrupts aagains each other and provides the interrupt vector to the CPU which uses this vector to fetch the address of the interrupt handler.

The NVIC also includes enable-bits for all interrupt sources. So, to have an interrupt processed by the CPU, for a typical MCU you have to enable the interrupt in two or three locations:

1. PRIMASK/BASEMASK in the CPU: last line of defense. These are the global interrupt gates. `PRIMASK is similar to the interrupt-enable bit in the status-register of the smaller CPUs, BASEMASK is part of interrupt-priority resolution (just ignore it for the beginning).
2. NVIC interrupt-enable bit for each peripheral interrupt source. E.g Timer, UART, SPI, etc. Many peripherals have multiple internal sources tied to this NVIC-line. (e.g UART rx and tx interrupt).
3. The interrupt-enable bits in the peripheral itself. E.g. UART rx-interrupt, tx interrupt, rxerror interrupt, etc.

Some peripherals might not have internal bits, so the last one might be missing.

To get things working, you should read the Reference Manaul (Family Guide, or similar), then there is often some "porgramming the Cortex-M4" howto (e.g ST has one for the STM32 series). You should also get the documents from ARM (they are available for free download).

Finally you need the CMSIS headers from your MCU vendor (TI here). These should be tailored for your MCU. You might have to provide some `#define's.

And, yes, this is quite some stuff to read. But imo it is worth the effort. Alternatively you might start with a book. There are some out which might be helpful to get the whole picture first (it is really hard to get from the single documents - yet possible).

Comment: That's useful, thanks. I'll definitely follow the advice when I go beyond the blinky.c stage.

Comment: @JeanAnthelme: Not trying to push, but may I ask why you did not accept the answer? What is missing?